# Elasticsearch - get all document indexed in past one day

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Does Elasticsearch gives in inbuild field or rest endpoint to get all the documents indexed in past 1 day.

Comment: That is usually achieved with creating time-based indices, i.e. one index per day for instance. You'd know exactly which documents have been indexed each day.

Comment: What if i cannot change the way data is indexed. It is an application running in production. Elasticsearch doesn't give any in built fields?  i was looking into it, "_timestamp" was one field but looks like tjey deprecated it. I was thinking about using _id as it is incremental but with latest version it is not integer anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: `_timestamp` has been deprecated in favor of either using a custom date field or time-based indices. So if you have a date field (like `@timestamp` from logstash maybe) then you could use it in a range query.